# (Inanimate) Nouns being used in a personal sense

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe when a noun is treated as a person, usually in marketing prose, e.g. "iPhone is capable of..." (rather than "the iPhone is capable of...")?

Comment: Are you sure the missing *the* in the example was on purpose and not by mistake? It sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphize):

> **Anthropomorphism** is a term [used] to refer to any attribution of human characteristics (or characteristics assumed to belong only to humans) to non-human animals or non-living things.

See also: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anthropomorphism).

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your example, but personification is the word I would use.

Answer (score 0):

"personalising" comes to mind.

In what context would you want to use a single word? Noun, verb, adjective?

Comment: Didn't necessarily have to be a single word, just a phrase to describe what's going on.  I thought of personalising, but it sounds too much like something you would do to make something your own.